# zombie.js visit() calling back too early (using browserify)

Tags: backbone.js, zombie.js

Im using zombie to test a backbone app, when I use zombie.visit, zombie calls the vows callback before all scripts on the page are loaded, so my backbone app isn't loaded. However if I wait for the 'done' event, i.e. `browser.on 'done', @callback` then my backbone app gets loaded before the callback is called.

Anyway to get the visit function to only callback once the 'done' event is received?

PS Im using browserify to load quite a large script including backbone/underscore/jquery and other jquery plugins

Answer (score 0):

I ran in to the same thing but, oddly, I used some of your other suggestions to use 'on done' to figure out a way to wait until the document was completely loaded (including any dynamically injected from JS stuffs!).

```
it('should have the correct title', function() {
    browser.on('done', function(doc) {
        console.log("DONE finally finito..");
        //console.log(browser.html());
        expect(doc.document.title).toMatch('.*Login'); 
        expect(doc.document.title).not.toEqual('XXXXX');
        asyncSpecDone(); 
    });
    browser.visit(LOGIN, function(err, doc) {
    });
    asyncSpecWait();
});
```

where LOGIN is a URL to my login page. the browser.html() printed out the full page and I saw the dynamically inserted elements as expected. FWIW, my application is using node .ejs files that express.js is compiling on the fly; but this will likely apply to any dynamically injected page that you want to test with zombie.

To my mind this looks like an anti-pattern and I would love if the author either corrects me or posts an alternative. However, this is a workaround.